Why is the LinkedIn API endpoint for fetching post reactions consistently returning 500 Internal Server Errors?
I'm using the LinkedIn API to fetch reactions for specific posts, and this was working fine for years until 09/18/2024.
Now, the endpoint consistently returns a 500 Internal Server Error no matter the URN. I haven't made any changes to my request format or authentication and other requests still succeed as expected.
I'm directly following the request format specified in the docs:
GET https://api.linkedin.com/rest/reactions/(entity:{entityUrn})?q=entity&sort=(value:REVERSE_CHRONOLOGICAL)

I've tried a dozen post URNs and the endpoint consistently returns the same error. I'm currently using API version 202306, but I've also tried other API versions with the same result.

Have you tried encoding the urn?
